# How to set first div width depends on text width, the remaining full width will be assign to second div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I want to split every row with two columns, and first div width depends on text width, the remaining full width will be assign to second div. I have attached my sample form design.

[image]

Comment: What about a jsfiddle with your current DOM and CSS?

Comment: Do you want label on 1st div and input on 2nd?

Comment: yes. first div label, second div will be input field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using `flex-box`, you can do it like this:

[**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/4H6u5/1/)
*Tested on:* Chrome, IE10, FF (that wht the CSS looks so messy)

**HTML:**

```
    <div class="Row">
        <div class="label"><label>short</label></div>
        <div class="input"><input type="text" value="text goes here" /></div>
    </div>
    <div class="Row">
        <div class="label"><label>this is a long label</label></div>
        <div class="input"><input type="text" value="text goes here" /></div>
    </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
*
{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.Row
{
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-direction: normal;
    -moz-box-direction: normal;
    -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
    -moz-box-orient: horizontal;
    -webkit-flex-direction: row;
    -ms-flex-direction: row;
    flex-direction: row;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: nowrap;
    -ms-flex-wrap: nowrap;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    -webkit-box-pack: start;
    -moz-box-pack: start;
    -webkit-justify-content: flex-start;
    -ms-flex-pack: start;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    -webkit-align-content: stretch;
    -ms-flex-line-pack: stretch;
    align-content: stretch;
    -webkit-box-align: start;
    -moz-box-align: start;
    -webkit-align-items: flex-start;
    -ms-flex-align: start;
    align-items: flex-start;
}

    .Row > div
    {
        -webkit-align-self: auto;
        -ms-flex-item-align: auto;
        align-self: auto;
    }

.label
{
    -webkit-box-flex: 0;
    -moz-box-flex: 0;
    -webkit-flex: 0 1 auto;
    -ms-flex: 0 1 auto;
    flex: 0 1 auto;
    /*apply padding if you want*/
}

.input
{
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    -moz-box-flex: 1;
    -webkit-flex: 1 0 auto;
    -ms-flex: 1 0 auto;
    flex: 1 0 auto;
    /*apply padding if you want*/
}
.input input
{
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

li .div1{float:left;}
li .div2{*zoom:1;overflow:hidden;}

Comment: some further explanation would help the OP